# insert pdf ocr data from file to database

Tags: java, oracle, ocr

I have done ocr of a pdf file using pdfbox open source library , currently its writing data into a **Text** file but i want to put all data in a **database** table

```
public class Pdfocr {

    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db";
    private static final String DB_USER = "user";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "pwd";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PDDocument pd;
        BufferedWriter wr;

        try {
            Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connection");
            Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

            //statement.execute("INSERT INTO xx_lockbox_receipts(BATCH, TRX, CHECK_DATE, LOCKBOX_NO, ACCT_NO, CHECK_NO, AMOUNT) VALUES (1,1,SYSDATE,123,123,321,10)");

            File input = new File("C:/ocr/MTBC lockbox deposits Feb 01, 2019 ($5,185.85).pdf");
            File output = new File("C:/ocr/SampleText.txt");
            pd = PDDocument.load(input);
            int i = pd.getNumberOfPages();

            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            stripper.setStartPage(1);
            stripper.setEndPage(i);
            wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
            stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.close();
            }
            wr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The SQL INSERT statement is mentioned in a comment in the code above; the output sample from the extracted text file is below:

```
Batch: 1, Tran: 1, Date: 20190201, Amount: 73.88, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: 1200653200, Check#: 1242
Batch: 1, Tran: 1, Date: 20190201, Amount: 0.00, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: -
Batch: 1, Tran: 2, Date: 20190201, Amount: 3440.91, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: 5020607192, Check#: 23322
Batch: 1, Tran: 2, Date: 20190201, Amount: 0.00, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: -
Batch: 1, Tran: 2, Date: 20190201, Amount: 0.00, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: -
Batch: 1, Tran: 2, Date: 20190201, Amount: 0.00, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: -
Batch: 1, Tran: 3, Date: 20190201, Amount: 1671.06, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: 3601085602, Check#: 8723
Batch: 1, Tran: 3, Date: 20190201, Amount: 0.00, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: -
Batch: 1, Tran: 3, Date: 20190201, Amount: 0.00, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: -
Batch: 1, Tran: 3, Date: 20190201, Amount: 0.00, Lockbox#: 83495, Acc#: -
```

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking... Do you want to know how to split a text line into elements?

Comment: I want to Split this string and insert into a database table

Comment: Then it would be better to create a new question that focuses on the core problem. Your question looks like a database / ocr problem but it isn't so people who are good with string parsing will disregard it. A solution would be to call `String.split(",")` on each line from your decoded text (you need to separate your text into lines too); then search each string for ": " and cut off there. (But there are many other solutions)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for suggestion i just want to know how can i convert BufferedWriter to String so i can split by `,` and insert it into db

Comment: I think you mean `BufferedReader` and `StringReader` to get lines. (But you could also use `split("\n")` although this will have a bigger memory footprint).

Comment: Yup thats why i need some Expert Solution for huge data

Comment: Then `BufferedReader.readLine()` and `StringReader(string)` are a good way to work. You could also extract the pages individually with the PDFBox stripper. As I wrote, I recommend that you create a new question that focuses only on the splitting, and show some working code, and remove any mention of PDFBox or databases.

Comment: Still confused how to use your idea in code i am going to open new question please share exact code to parse data and insert to db

Comment: The text extraction string can be used as input for the `StringReader` constructor. Chain that one to the `BufferedReader` constructor. Now `BufferedReader` has a `readLine()` method which will get you lines. And these you can split as described in a previous comment.